# How to add keys the proper way to this react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get warnings about missing keys on GridRow in the following code. I have read about it but I do not find a way to apply it to the react component? It seems like I have to do it in the final render method but I don't have any data there?

```
var data1 = {"Columns":[{"Title":"Title1","HTMLClass":"g1_Title"},{"Title":"Title2","HTMLClass":"g2_Title"},{"Title":"Title3","HTMLClass":"g3_Title"}],"Rows":[{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]},{"Cells":["Cell0","Cell1","Cell2"]}]};


var GridRow = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var data = [], columns;

        if(this.props.columns){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.props.columns.length; i++){
                data.push({
                    HTMLclass: this.props.columns[i].HTMLClass,
                    content: this.props.cells[i]
                })
            }
        }


        columns = data.map(function(col) {
            return (
                <div className={col.HTMLclass}>{col.content}</div>
            );
        }.bind(this));

        return (
            <li>
                {columns}
            </li>
        );
    }
});
var GridHead = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var cell = this.props.data.Title;
            var htmlClass = this.props.data.HTMLClass;
        }
        return (
            <div className={htmlClass}>{cell}</div>
        );
    }
});
var GridList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        if(this.props.data){
            var header = this.props.data.Columns.map(function (columns, i) {
                return (
                    <GridHead data={columns} key={i} />
                );
            });
            var row = this.props.data.Rows.map(function (row, i) {
                return (
                    <GridRow columns={data1.Columns} cells={row.Cells} key={i} />
                );
            });
        }
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>{header}</li>
                {row}
            </ul>
        );
    }
});


var GridBox = React.createClass({
    loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          this.setState({ data: data });
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { data: this.props.initial };
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <GridList data={data1} />
        );
    }
});
```

> Warning : Each child in an array should have a unique "key" prop.
>   Check the render method of GridRow. See
>   [fb.me/react-warning-keys](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the key to your column div, React just needs some unique identifier so it can keep it's Virtual DOM diff up-to-date.

The key can be anything, just as long as it's unique.

```
columns = data.map(function(col, i) {
    return (
        <div className={col.HTMLclass}>{col.content} key={i}></div>
    );
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Okay, I thought I hade to add it to the li element. So all I really have to do is to add a key to the childe farthest down the chain?

Answer (score 0):

The key should only be set to the index if there are no other options.